# Left and right column problems

Tags: html, css

When my page content exceeds the minimum height of the div I want both columns to expand with it. At the moment when the left div exceeds the right, there's white space underneath the right div, but I want the right background to repeat with the size of the left.

http://thinkingparentsforum.prettypollution.com/blog

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).